# How to run command with tcsh and keep the shell alive?

Tags: linux, tcsh

I'm using tcsh. I want to open a new interactive tcsh shell and run command. I want to do it like:

```
tcsh -c <command>
```

The problem is that tcsh executes the command and exits the interactive shell. I tried using `-i` option but it didn't work. How can I enter tcsh, run the command and stay in the shell?

An example: `tcsh -c echo hi` will open a new shell, run `echo hi` and stay in it.

Comment: Why not just run `tcsh` to open the shell, do what you need, and then exit afterwards?

Comment: It's automated. Perl runs: `tcsh` and then it runs the `echo hi`. If I won't exit from `tcsh`, it won't run `echo hi`.

Comment: What do you mean "If I won't exit from `tcsh`, it won't run `echo hi`? Why would that matter? You stated that you want to stay in the shell so Perl opening the shell notwithstanding, run `tcsh` to open a session in that shell, and then do you what you need and exit it when you are done. You want to run `echo hi` in the `tcsh` shell so why do you need it to exit? If this isn't making sense, then you need to edit your question and add more details of what you are trying to do and what isn't working.